# Why do Russian rocket engineers call C₂H₈N₂ "heptyl"?

Tags: fuel, terminology, russia

[Unsymmetrical dimethlyhydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsymmetrical_dimethylhydrazine) or "UDMH" is a propellant which has been used by Russian, American, European, Chinese, and Indian rockets.

[image: unsymmetrical dimethylhydrazine]

Russian rocket engineers nickname it "heptyl".  **Why was this name chosen**, especially when it means a compound with [7 carbon atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptyl), and UDMH has only two?

---

**Addendum:** As several commenters also seem to believe, my suspicion is that the name was chosen as a codeword during the Cold War to deceive enemies.  However, that is merely a guess, which I why I originally asked

> (Support your answer with sources; no speculation please.)

The [article cited by Wikipedia](https://www.theverge.com/2013/7/2/4487096/russian-rocket-explosion-proton-heptyl-contamination) states only

> To be specific, the Proton-M — a booster rocket used for decades to carry commercial and military payloads — relies on a combination of unsymmetrical dimethylhydrazine (**better known as heptyl fuel**) and nitrogen tetroxide.

without providing any source for that claim, and *no reason why that name was chosen*.

---

Related:

- [Are MMH and UDMH interchangeable?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1188/26446)
- [Would symmetrical dimethylhydrazine work as a hypergolic fuel?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43201/26446)

Comment: sometimes I'll post links to my chemistry-related questions in [The Periodic Table](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) but I don't know if it would be helpful in this case

Comment: From Wikipedia: "UDMH (which is referred to as "heptyl" [codename from Soviet era] by Russian engineers" If it was a codename, it should not be related to seven carbon atoms. The name should give no information about the compound to the cold war enemies.

Comment: There is C7H20N2O4S called Heptylhydrazine sulphate. It has 7 carbon atoms. May be the cold war code name should indicate this compound while in fact UDMH was used.

Comment: There is also Heptylhydrazine C7H18N2

Comment: @Uwe A codename could be chosen to deliberately give the wrong information rather than to give no information.

Comment: There are many examples when something related to Soviet military secrets has a name that should confuse spies.